# Print Email that will Fit in a Single Page

Tags: css, printing, html-email

I want to print an email and fit it to just one page.
I want to remove the Header and Footer.
I want it to do it via `@media print`

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

You can achieve this by adding a class with `display:none;` to the elements you wish to hide.

```
@media print {
    .noprint {
        display:none;
    }
}
```

## Support

Please be aware that this has limited support.
[image]

You can find more information here - https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/email-marketing/2006/06/can-i-include-a-print-styleshe/ although it is a rather old article things haven't moved on a great deal.